# How to show table row on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, onclick, row

I have a table with several rows, all of which except the first is hidden. I have added a button that I would like the user to be able to click to display more rows of the table individually. However, I cannot append these rows to the table, because that would increase the row count overall and throw off the print style sheet. I am not the best at Javscript, but I am hoping there is a way to use Javascript or jQuery to click the button and show the next table row, and if another table row is needed the user can click the "add more" button again to show the next table row. I have listed the max table rows in the HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonniebauer/j5agK/2/

**HTML**

```
<table id="processing_table">
<tr>
<td class="table_label">
    Quantity
</td>
<td class="table_qty">
    <input type="text" id="qty1" placeholder="Qty"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Description <span id="processing_small_header">(Vendor, Model/Name, and Version)</span>
</td>
<td class="table_description">
    <input type="text" id="description1" placeholder="Description"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Connection
</td>
<td class="table_connection">
    <input type="text" id="connection1" placeholder="Type"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Template
</td>
<td class="table_template">
    <input type="text" id="template1" placeholder="Template"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table_label">
    Quantity
</td>
<td class="table_qty">
    <input type="text" id="qty2" name="more_fields" placeholder="Qty"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Description <span id="processing_small_header">(Vendor, Model/Name, and Version)</span>
</td>
<td class="table_description">
    <input type="text" id="description2" name="more_fields" placeholder="Description"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Connection
</td>
<td class="table_connection">
    <input type="text" id="connection2" name="more_fields" placeholder="Type"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Template
</td>
<td class="table_template">
    <input type="text" id="template2" name="more_fields" placeholder="Template"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table_label">
    Quantity
</td>
<td class="table_qty">
    <input type="text" id="qty3" placeholder="Qty"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Description <span id="processing_small_header">(Vendor, Model/Name, and Version)</span>
</td>
<td class="table_description">
    <input type="text" id="description3" placeholder="Description"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Connection
</td>
<td class="table_connection">
    <input type="text" id="connection3" placeholder="Type"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Template
</td>
<td class="table_template">
    <input type="text" id="template3" placeholder="Template"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table_label">
    Quantity
</td>
<td class="table_qty">
    <input type="text" id="qty4" placeholder="Qty"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Description <span id="processing_small_header">(Vendor, Model/Name, and Version)</span>
</td>
<td class="table_description">
    <input type="text" id="description4" placeholder="Description"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Connection
</td>
<td class="table_connection">
    <input type="text" id="connection4" placeholder="Type"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Template
</td>
<td class="table_template"/>
    <input type="text" id="template4" placeholder="Template"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table_label">
    Quantity
</td>
<td class="table_qty">
    <input type="text" id="qty5" placeholder="Qty"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Description <span id="processing_small_header">(Vendor, Model/Name, and Version)</span>
</td>
<td class="table_description">
    <input type="text" id="description5" placeholder="Description"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Connection
</td>
<td class="table_connection">
    <input type="text" id="connection5" placeholder="Type"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Template
</td>
<td class="table_template">
    <input type="text" id="template5" placeholder="Template"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table_label">
    Quantity
</td>
<td class="table_qty">
    <input type="text" id="qty6" placeholder="Qty"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Description <span id="processing_small_header">(Vendor, Model/Name, and Version)</span>
</td>
<td class="table_description">
    <input type="text" id="description6" placeholder="Description"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Connection
</td>
<td class="table_connection">
    <input type="text" id="connection6" placeholder="Type"/>
</td>
<td class="table_label">
    Template
</td>
<td class="table_template">
    <input type="text" id="template6" placeholder="Template"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#add_more').click(function() {
document.getElementById('#processing_table tr').style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: Do you really need to show a "row" format, or could it be a simple popup/hidden div that contains the info?

Comment: I can wrap the rows in divs. I would like all of the <td> in each row to show on one click like a "section," so wrapping in a div would work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did something "similar" this week.

Row of information in a table (7 columns) with three hidden columns.
You see the table in a scrolling div and when you roll over the row, a div in the lower right hand corner of the screen shows the hidden columns. You might adapt something similar.

The HTML is simple, similar to this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id='XX" display:none>....
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id='XX" display:none>....
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id='XX" display:none>....
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id='XX" display:none>....
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id='XX" display:none>....
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS uses this to style each column:

```
#centraltable tbody td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 6em;
    text-align: center;}
```

Here is the js:

```
$('.rolloverdiv').hide();


$('#centraltable tbody tr').mouseover(function(){
      $('.rolloverdiv').show();
            var appcomments = $(this).find('#comm').html();
      $('.rolloverdiv').html("Comments: <span class='span1'>" + appcomments + "</span>");
                                           });

$('#centraltable tbody tr').mouseout(function(e){
                                           $('.rolloverdiv').hide();
                                           });
```

It's Neanderthal code, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a CodePen, please take a look.

```
`https://codepen.io/trgiangvp3/full/PKKMWr/`
```

I presume you know clearly how many rows does your table have.
So, my idea is as below:

1. Hide all the table's row except the first row at onload event.
2. In the addNewRow function, I'm going to check the current visible rows count and show the next row if there are any row invisible.